# Why get unsupported child for menu exception in zk?

Tags: java, zk

I have this zk code:

```
<zk>
    <window apply="org.zkoss.bind.BindComposer" viewModel="@id('vm')@init('IndexViewModel')" validationMessages="@id('vmsgs')">
        <menubar>
            <menu>
                <menuitem label="${each}" forEach="@load(vm.menupoints)" />
            </menu>
        </menubar>
    </window>
</zk>
```

in my view model:

```
    private List<String> menupoints = Arrays.asList("Home", "ShipTracking");
    //getter-setter
```

But i get a `index.zul: org.zkoss.zk.ui.UiException: Unsupported child for menu:`  exception...what can be a problem? My goal is to create a menu with different content...may be can anybody help with it also? 
 Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Menuitem is not a supported child of menu.

If you look at the [documentation](https://www.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK%20Component%20Reference/Essential%20Components/Menu) you see that it only supports `menupopup`

```
<menu>
    <menupopup>
        <menuitem label="${each}" forEach="@load(vm.menupoints)" />
    </menupopup>
</menu>
```